# How to make FindBoost.cmake work?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

One executable in my project depends on `boost`. The headers and libs are in custom directories, say **dirA** and **dirB**. I have included

```
find_package(boost)
```

in the `CMakeLists.txt`, but it outputs

```
-- Could NOT find Boost
```

when `cmake ..` is executed in the `build/` under project directory.

Since the `CMakeLists.txt` is part of the public project, I don't want **dirA** and **dirB** hardcoded in it. Is there a way to make `FindBoost.cmake` work by changing something locally? Say modify `FindBoost.cmake`, or set some environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [documentation for FindBoost](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module%3aFindBoost):

> BOOST_ROOT             - Preferred installation prefix
>
> [...]
>
> Note that some hint names start in upper-case "BOOST". One may specify
>   these as environment variables if they are not specified as CMake
>   variables or cache entries.

Have the `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable point to the Boost directory on your machine and CMake should be able to find it automatically.